# My mist browser Win64 0.6.2 doesn't show up

Tags: mist, wallets, browsers

I was downloading the blocks in the test-network and when I noticed it stopped downloading. I decided to restart the app. resulting into this: [image: white screen]

[image: For a brief second]

This is what I see for a brief second before showing the first picture, what can I do. The wallet is still on the test-network. I don't know how to put it back to the main net.

Redownloaded, restarted my pc didn't fix the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself by downloading a previous version.